# Mark as one some specific coordinates to create a binary image?

Tags: python, image

i have coordinate of some points that has been extracted by an algorithm.

```
fd=[[11.123040199279785, 221.54373168945312], [11.491310119628906, 157.2677764892578], [18.584421157836914, 129.27955627441406], [110.09223175048828, 38.664451599121094], [116.26483154296875, 198.57406616210938], [124.06718444824219, 222.397216796875], [127.4659194946289, 37.52345657348633], [131.89353942871094, 57.83112716674805], [137.85240173339844, 182.58563232421875], [145.13601684570312, 41.06821060180664], [146.40333557128906, 212.8253936767578], [151.6497802734375, 103.33809661865234]]
```

I am receiving an error:

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

This is the code:

```
template=np.asarray(img[d_idx]).astype(np.bool)
for i in range(len(fd)):
    point=fd[i]
    template[point]=1
```

How to define a new blank image and make these coordinates 1?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
What you post is a 2D list, not a particular image format.  "Make these coordinates 1" is no clear.  Why can't you use a `for` loop?

Comment: @Prune , Thanks for your comment. I want to create a binary image which the values in those coordinates should be one.

Comment: what do you mean "in those coordinates"?
how do you map coordinate to pixel in the image?
@S.EB

Comment: I'm still confused about where you're stuck.  Changing all values of a list is a straightforward list comprehension, covered well in various tutorials and other SO postings.  Again, please follow the "how to ask" guidelines.

Comment: @Prune I am getting an error that is why I posted this question. I updated the question. I hope this time is clear. thanks

Comment: [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Your coordinates are floats. There is no pixel at, say, `(0.3, 1.5)`. You need to quantize the floating point values into integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have floating point values, not integers. You must quantize these values to integers somehow in order to create an image, which has pixels. The easiest way to do this is nearest neighbor / rounding:

```
x_resolution = 1000
y_resolution = 1000

x_min = 0
x_max = 10
x_ptp = x_max - x_min

y_min = 0
y_max = 10
y_ptp = y_max - y_min

img = np.zeros((y_resolution, x_resolution), dtype=np.bool)

for x, y in points:
    x_pxl = (x - x_min) / x_ptp * x_resolution
    y_pxl = (y - y_min) / y_ptp * y_resolution
    img[y_pxl, x_pxl] = 1
```

If you want fancy effects, like anti-aliasing or width to these points, you're going to need something more advanced than generating the image yourself. Consider just [scatter plotting the points using matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/shapes_and_collections/scatter.html) instead.